# Fatal error: Uncaught Table 'ramscoremod1.pss_paypal_login_user' doesn't exist

Tags: paypal, prestashop

I am using PRestashop 1.6.1 and Paypal.
And for a few days, without any updates, I have a Fatal Error when I try to pay a order...

> Fatal error: Uncaught Table 'mydb.pss_paypal_login_user' doesn't exist
>   SELECT `id_paypal_login_user` FROM `pss_paypal_login_user` WHERE 1 AND
>   `id_customer` = '403'  thrown in /home/mywebsite/www/classes/db/Db.php
>   on line 646

Comment: Did you check if the table exists?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Actually the table didn't exist, so I created it and it seems to work.........